# Cookie Issue in iframe Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer, cookies

I am trying to open a webview iframe. Problem is that Internet explorer (11) doesn't set cookie for webpage loaded in iframe. It works fine in chrome, firefox and even in Edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer supports a cookie-restricting privacy feature called P3P. Web developers often get tripped up by it because no other browser implements the P3P standard.

To get IE to accept cookies from your server in a 3rd-party context (or to get IE to resend a previously-set cookie to your server when it is accessed in a 3rd-party context), you must declare the privacy policy that governs how your cookies will be used. That declaration takes the form of a P3P header on the HTTP response (or, less commonly, a META tag with the same content).

For more detailed information, please refer link below will be helpful to understand and solve the issue.

Reference:

[A Quick Look at P3P](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2013/09/17/a-quick-look-at-p3p/)